# CSS for adding 'Pop Up' Effect for Custom Modal in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a page consisting of a component Main.

Main further contains two components - NavBar and Body. Body also contains two components - ViewTable and AddPerson. Inside the ViewTable component, I want a modal to load when a field in the table is clicked. I've got the functionality right but I'm stuck at the CSS part.

Right now, the modal looks like this -
[image: Here, the modal comes on top of the table and I want it to overlap the table.]

How should I go about doing so? I'm new to React and the component structure

Comment: Can you add more specific details on what you intend to achieve? That'd be easier for the community

Comment: @UdayaPrakash I want the modal to appear on top of the table. I want to understand the CSS for this. I did search for it but the answers available don't seem to help me maybe because of how my app is layered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good react library called *react-modal* i can recommend. It's a bit hard to get into but once you get it to work it's great.

If you want to do it the vanilla way, use *position: absolute* for the modal. To get the transition to work, use *react-transition-group* to toggle the opacity and animate the transition. It'll probably take some time to get into react-transition-group since it's a bit confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @gian.gyger, react-modal with react-transition-group is the right way to go.

But, if you have already implemented the modal with plain react and want help with CSS alone, this could help. To make the modal position fixed so that it doesn't occupy space in the lower layer, we could give the following

```
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  /* for darker background when modal is open*/

    /*z-index sets the modal on the higher stack above all of the others */
    z-index:10
}

.modal {
    width: 50%; /* or above or lesser */
    background: red; /* modal background color */
    margin: 20% auto;
}
```

Here, I am assuming that element with `modal-container` class is activated only upon the desired action (like, a button click) and `modal-container` is an empty div that just contains within it the `modal` element

Reference: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as correct if it helps @sindhugauri